# Weird SeriesData behavior?

Tags: functions, series-expansion

I was trying to calculate the determinant of a matrix whose elements are truncated series. As a result I obtained an expression like this:

```
S = SeriesData[x, DirectedInfinity[1], {a, 0, b, 0, c, d}, -9, -3, 2]
```

[image: out1]

I attempted to further manipulate `S` but encountered something unusual:

```
S1 = (S/x^2 - d)*x^2
S2 = S - d*x^2
```

[image: out23]

Clearly, `S1` should be the correct answer mathematically. It seems that accuracy is somehow lost in `S2`, and something similar happens if I try to eliminate another term:

```
S3 = (S/x^(5/2) - c)*x^(5/2)
S4 = S - c*x^(5/2)
```

[image: out45]

Again, `S3` is the correct answer. So far it seemed that the order of the term subtracted from `S` determines how much accuracy is lost. However, trying to eliminate the next term proves otherwise:

```
S5 = (S/x^(7/2) - b)*x^(7/2)
S6 = S - b*x^(7/2)
```

[image: out67]

Subtracting higher order terms, such as `a*x^(9/2)` results in the same remainder as in `Out[5]` and `Out[7]`. I am wondering what is happening here, especially since there is no error message or warning of any kind. Since there is no warning, is there any other way to catch such behavior? If this is absolutely unavoidable, is there an alternative, possibly safer way to work with asymptotic approximations?

UPDATE (06/29/2016):
Wolfram confirmed that it is a bug. They said they are working on it. I will post an update again when they fix it.

Comment: It seems localized to `nmax` being `-3` or less, from `-1` it works as expected. Could it have to do with the expansion point?

Answer (score 1):

Use Normal to get the polynomial out. Then work with it. The O[...] term can do funny things that are not obvious.

```
In[2]:= SS = Normal[S]

Out[2]= a/(1/x)^(9/2) + b/(1/x)^(7/2) + c/(1/x)^(5/2) + d x^2

In[7]:= S1 = FullSimplify[(SS/x^2 - d)*x^2]
S2 = FullSimplify[SS - d*x^2]

Out[7]= (c + x (b + a x))/(1/x)^(5/2)

Out[8]= (c + x (b + a x))/(1/x)^(5/2)

In[9]:= S1 === S2

Out[9]= True
```

Comment: The O[...] term is crucial for my purposes. I implemented a safe way to extract and work with the known polynomial terms of an approximation, but then at each operation (e.g. addition or multiplication of series) I need to handle the remainder separately. Nonetheless, my question is mostly about why we see this behavior.